# 3 dimensional array in C changes values after the for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am really at odds in this one. I am populating a three dimensional array in C as follows:

```
double maxEval = 0;        
double Evals[2][le-1];  
double Waves[2][2][le-1];

for(int i=0; i<le-1; i++){

  getEvalsandWaves(&Evals[0][i], &Evals[1][i], &Waves[0][0][i], &Waves[0][1][i],
                   &Waves[1][0][i], &Waves[1][1][i], g, dx, &maxEval,
                   Q[0][i], Q[0][i+1], Q[1][i], Q[1][i+1]);

  if(myRank==0){
    printf("i= %d, %f  %f\n",i,Waves[0][0][i],Waves[0][1][i]);
    printf("       %f  %f\n\n",Waves[1][0][i],Waves[1][1][i]);
  }
}
```

The proto function and function for getEvalsandWaves are here:

```
/*The objective of this function is to calculate eigenvalues which have a close*/
/*form (e1 and e2) as well as the wave speeds associated with each eigenvalue  */
/*[w00; w10]) and [w01;w11] which then are stored in a thee dimensional matrix */

void getEvalsandWaves(double *e1, double *e2, double *w00,double *w01, double *w10,
                      double *w11, double g,double dx, double *max, double him, 
                      double hi, double uim, double ui);

void getEvalsandWaves(double *e1, double *e2, double *w00, double *w01, double *w10, 
                      double *w11, double g, double dx, double *max, double him, 
                      double hi, double uim, double ui){

                      double hbar=0; double ubar=0;

                      /*this function only returns the Roe averages */
                      /*using the values him,hi,uim,ui which are all*/
                      /*doubles */
                      RoeAvg(&hbar, &ubar,him,hi,uim,ui);

                      (*e1) = ubar - sqrt(g*hbar);
                      (*e2) = ubar + sqrt(g*hbar);

                      /*I tried to use this values instead of (*e1) and (*e2)*/
                      /*in calculating the w'sbelow to see if it fixed the   */
                      /*problem but it didn't work.                          */
                      double ei1 = ubar - sqrt(g*hbar);
                      double ei2 = ubar + sqrt(g*hbar);

                      if(fabs((*e1))>(*max))
                      (*max)=fabs((*e1));

                      if(abs((*e2))>(*max))
                      (*max)=fabs((*e2));

                      double c = 1/(2*sqrt(g*hbar));

                      (*w00) = c * ( ei2*(hi-him)+(ui-uim) ) * 1;      
                      (*w01) = c * ( (-1)*ei1*(hi-him)-(ui-uim) ) * 1;
                      (*w10) = c * ( ei2*(hi-him)+(ui-uim) ) * ei1;    
                      (*w11) = c * ( (-1)*ei1*(hi-him)-(ui-uim) ) * ei2;
}
```

So here is where I don't know what is happening. If you notice inside the for loop I am printing the values for the three dimensional array Waves giving the following sample output:

```
...
i= 47, 0.000000  0.000000
       -0.000000  0.000000

i= 48, 0.000000  0.000000
       -0.000000  0.000000

i= 49, -1.000000  -1.000000
        1.414214  -1.414214
...
```

which are the correct values. However if I print the values of Waves immediately after the for loop this is what I get:

```
...
i= 47, 0.000000  0.000000
      -1.000000  -1.000000

i= 48, 0.000000  0.000000
       0.000000  0.000000

i= 49, -1.000000  -1.000000
        0.000000  0.000000
...
```

I really can't see why the values change when the for loop is finalized. Any help would be greatly appreciated.(The Evals array and the maxEval variable do keep the right values after the loop.)

Comment: That are some scary functions. If you expect someone helping, commenting your code might help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I commented the functions with a rough explanation of what they're suppose to do.

Comment: Unfortunately the comments are useless. Example: “this function only returns the Roe averages using the values him,hi,uim,ui which are all doubles.” – This conveys **no information** that isn’t already in the code (inspecting the function name and the arguments). The comments need to provide *additional* information, not repeat the code in more verbose form.

Comment: Just an FYI: if your arrays are of size `x`, a `for(...)` loop terminating condition of `...;i < x;...` will never reach `list_member[x]` <== maybe you did this on purpose?

Comment: Have you made progress? Where and how do you print the values after the loop? Seems important, especially if you think they keep the right values after the loop--also, how do you know they keep the correct values, anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those that took the time to read my question and sorry for the late response to some of the comments but I got busy with another project.

So, I resolved the issue after reading through this post:

[How are 3D arrays stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920944/how-are-3d-arrays-stored-in-c)

So I know my comments did't help at all trying to explain what I was doing but in the end it boiled down trying to store an array of matrices. So we can think of a an array A[x][y] as a two dimensional array and I wanted to store z of them as A[x][y][z].

I knew that C stores two dimensional arrays as linear ones but after reading the article in the link above I realized that if I tried to store say 7 in the third matrix in the array in position [0][1] as:

```
A[0][1][3]=7;
```

and then tried to retrieve it later I would get something different. The reason being that if I tried to store it in this way I had to take into account how C stores a three dimensional array as a 1-D array and thus the indices would be different.

I should had been reading A[x][y][z] as an array of x arrays each with z elements. At the end for my purposes (storing an array of z matrices) what work was:

```
A[z][x][y];
A[3][0][1]=7;
```

That way if I later retrieve,

```
printf("The value at A[3][0][1]= %d",A[3][0][1]);
```

it would print the correct value of seven.

The article makes a better job explaining what I just tried to say. If anyone has more ideas or comments please let me know.