# In chaos regarding function of pointers in C Language

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a program to test pointer actions but I didn't get the logic behind output.

As if I use `arr+1` then instead of 2nd location I get 7th and similar is the case with `*arr+1` and I feel weird for `*` expression is showing address not value.

CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN OUTPUT, PLEASE !

Program is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int arr[2][3][2] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        int i,j,k;
        printf("%d\t",arr);
        printf("%d\t",*arr);
        printf("%d\n",**arr);
        printf("%d\n",***arr);
        printf("%d\t",arr+1);
        printf("%d\t",*arr+1);
        printf("%d\n",**arr+1);
        printf("%d\n",***arr+1);
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
            for(k=0;k<2;k++)
                printf("%d      %u \n",*(*(*(arr+i)+j)+k),&arr[i][j][k]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
return 0;
}
```

And OUTPUT is:

```
4202512 4202512 4202512
1
4202536 4202520 4202516
2
1      4202512
2      4202516

3      4202520
4      4202524

5      4202528
6      4202532

7      4202536
8      4202540

9      4202544
10      4202548

11      4202552
12      4202556
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you declare a `int [2][3][2]` array, which means that:

- the type of the expression `arr` is an `int [2][3][2]` array, so you can only get a pointer from that type.
- the type of the expression `arr[0]`, or `*arr` is an `int [3][2]` array, so you can only get a pointer from that type.
- the type of the expression `arr[0][0]`, or `**arr` is an `int [2]` array, so you can only get a pointer from that type.
- the type of the expression `arr[0][0][0]`, or `***arr` is an `int`, so you can only get a `int` value from that type.

variations of this process will give similar outcome.

you always get a same base address because multidimensional arrays are flat in memory and dimension sizes are used for partitioning that flat memory.

`int [2][2]` is like:

```
0, 1
2, 3
```

Where the numbers resemble the order of elements in memory, and the bidimensional display resemble the array's line/column access.

Answer (score 1):

Your first 3 prints are showing you the same address but have different meanings (and types)-

1. `arr` is the address of your entire 3d array, of type `int***` (you cast the pointer to int, not a good practice since on some systems it may be bigger)
2. `*arr` is the address of the "flattened" 2d array of type `int**`, effectively located at `arr[0]`
3. `**arr` is the address of the twice "flattened" 1d array of type `int*`, effectively located at `arr[0][0]`
4. Only `***arr` finally brings you to an actual int value of `arr[0][0][0]`

Now you start pointer arithmetics, that's determined by the type of the pointer as mentioned abode and by the size of each dimension (which is known to the compiler). So:

1. `arr+1` gives you the address of `arr[1]`, which is removed from `arr[0]` by the length of 2*3 int elements (6*4=24 here)
2. `*arr+1` gives you the address `arr[0][1]`, which is removed from `arr[0][0]` by the length of 2 int elements (2*4=8 here)
3. `**arr+1` gives you the address of `arr[0][0][1]`, which is removed from `arr[0][0][0]` by the length of one int element (4 here)
4. `***arr+1` gives you `arr[0][0][1]`, which is simply `2`

See also this answer - [How are 3D arrays stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920944/how-are-3d-arrays-stored-in-c)