# Combining matrices with different dimensions in an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'd like to know if there is a way to combine two matrices with different dimensions into an array. I know there is the function abind(), but that function does not allow for different dimensions of the matrices. I need this because I use JAGS (with either R2jags or rjags) and these packages do not allow the data to be in list form. It does however work when I enter an array.

When I have the following two matrices:

```
a <- matrix(0, 3, 2)
b <- matrix(0, 4, 6)
a

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

b

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
```

I would ideally have it like this:

```
abind(a,b, along = 3)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to think of the matrices as one dimmensional arrays, which technically they are.

If you look at a matrix `'a'` that is `3X3` and you try to access `a[2][1]` for example it is equivallent to `a[2*3 + 1]`. You can use this to just traverse your matrices and combine them.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the a[2*3+1]? If I have the following matrix     a <- matrix(1:6, 3, 2), then a[2][1] is 2. How does your solution result in the same value?

Comment: Do you mean a three dimensional matrix with sizes (6,3,2)?
Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920944/how-are-3d-arrays-stored-in-c

Comment: No a 2D matrix with values 1:6, 3 rows and 2 columns :)

Comment: In a 2D array with X rows and Y columns array a[i][j] = a[i*x + j]
It means the same thing

Answer (score -1):

```
d=list(a,b)
```

i hope this is what do you want
it's just like this

Comment: The OP wants to combine matrices "into an array", not a list.