# 2 dimensional array manipulation

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a (10x10) 2 dimensional character array to store either ' ' and 'T' and display it like this

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The function I wrote:

```
  int plant_forest(char forest[][SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    forest[0][0] = ' ';
    for(i = 0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            if(forest[i][j]!= forest[0][0])
            {
                if(forest[i][j-1]!='T' && forest[i-1][j]!= 'T')
                {
                    forest[i][j] = 'T';
                }
                else
                {
                    forest[i][j] = ' ';
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result I got was slightly different.

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |T| |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| | |T| |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| | |T| |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| | |T| |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| | |T| |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| | |T| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| | |T| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| |T| |T| |T| | |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |T| |T| |T| |T| | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I checked the logic and couldn't find anything wrong. Except from i-1 and j-1 could be negative number. But how would this effecting the execution ?

Just for reference, I will include the printing function here. But I have already checked and sure that there was no error in this function

```
void printBoard(char forest[][SIZE])
{
    int i,j;

        printf("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n");
        for(i = 0; i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            for(j = 0;j<SIZE;j++)
            {
                printf("|%c",forest[i][j]);
            }
            printf("|\n");
            printf("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n");

        }

}
```

Comment: `[j-1]` - but `j` starts at 0! Not to mention apart from `[0][0]` `forest` is uninitialized. What you have looks massively over complicated (and quite buggy) just to get a "checkerboard".

Comment: forest is initialized in main function.

Comment: To make a checkerboard: `forest[i][j] = (i+j)&1 ? 'T' : ' ';`

Comment: can you further explain (i+j)&1 in forest[i][j] = (i+j)&1

Comment: `(i+j)&1` checks if `i+j` is an odd number. To understand why that makes a checkerboard, draw a 4x4 grid on a sheet of paper. Write the i,j values in each square, and compute the sum. Note where the sums are odd.

Comment: @TamLam: How about looking up the operators yourself? Would be a good exercise and you can better explain to your tutor.

Comment: @TamLam it's a cheesy way of writing `(i + j) % 2`

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have to do with how the data in the array is stored. In memory, the data is just stored [sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920944/how-are-3d-arrays-stored-in-c). Since [negative array indexes are allowed in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473675/are-negative-array-indexes-allowed-in-c) the functional outcome in your case is that forest[1][-1] points to the same data located in cell forest[0][9], which you will note is 'T'.

Because forest[0][9] (aka forest[1][-1]) is 'T', you fail this test

```
if(forest[i][j-1]!='T' && forest[i-1][j]!= 'T')
```

Which means that a ' ' is registered in cell forest[1][0] instead. Prevent negative index values, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-thinking the logic you are using to fill the `forest` array in `plant_forest`. All you need to stagger the `'T'` and `' '` elements used to fill `forest` is a check on whether your outer loop index `'i'` is *odd or even* and start filling with either a `'T'` or `' '` based on the result. Then just *toggle* between `'T'` and `' '` for each `'j'` index. For example:

```
int plant_forest (char (*forest)[SIZE])
{
    if (!forest) return 1;              /* validate pointer */
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        int t = i & 1;
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)   /* simple toggle 'T' or ' ' */
            forest[i][j] = t ? 'T' : ' ', t ^= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can test the results with a simple bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int plant_forest (char (*forest)[SIZE])
{
    if (!forest) return 1;              /* validate pointer */
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        int t = i & 1;
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)   /* simple toggle 'T' or ' ' */
            forest[i][j] = t ? 'T' : ' ', t ^= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {

    char arr[SIZE][SIZE] = {{0}};

    if (!plant_forest (arr)) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                putchar (arr[i][j]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/plant
 T T T T T
T T T T T
 T T T T T
T T T T T
 T T T T T
T T T T T
 T T T T T
T T T T T
 T T T T T
T T T T T
```

If you have any questions, or if I misunderstood your question, just let me know. (I'll leave it to you to fill in all the additional `'|'` formatting your may like).

You can even save a line of code as mentioned in the comments by anding the sum of `i` and `j`, in `plant_forest` to choose between assigning `'T'` or `' '` e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)   /* simple toggle 'T' or ' ' */
            forest[i][j] = (i + j) & 1 ? 'T' : ' ';
```

Either way will insure your `forest` array is populated correctly.