# Two-dimensional array of int arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is this possible? I need to make a 2d array and each element is supposed to have an int array of size 2.

So if I make a 10x10 array I need each index to have a [x, y] where x and y are ints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are 3D arrays stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920944/how-are-3d-arrays-stored-in-c)

Comment: `int array[10][10][2];` or `struct pair { int x, y; } array[10][10];`

Comment: Please google before asking: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: You can have more than 3 dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int array[10][10][2];
```

Here you have a 3D array. Where the 2D array : array[..][..] has 2 elements inside it.

Or you can use structure.

```
struct number {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

then :

```
struct number array[10][10];
```

Comment: 1. `s/Struct/struct/` 2. `s/number array/struct number array/`

Comment: Yeah thanks! I figured after asking it was simply a 3d array... Sorry for the people I annoyed for asking this!